# Distinguish notification center hiding and returning from background with DidBecomeActive notification

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I'm confused about `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification`. I can register an observer for this notification, and receive signals when the app becomes active from the background or when being launched. However, when I pull down the hidden top popup view (for general information: notifications, weather, stock market) then pull up to hide it, the signal is also generated. 
I use a callback method hooked with this signal to refresh my app, so this can be annoying for users of my app.

Can anybody help me differentiate these cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should try UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification, the apple doc has said:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html

> UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification: Posted when the application becomes active.
>
> > An application is active when it is receiving events. An active application can be said to have focus. It gains focus after being launched, loses focus when an overlay window pops up or when the device is locked, and gains focus when the device is unlocked.

Comment: Yes, you are true, the notification UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification will fire when the app becomes active from background or being launched but not from disappearing of any popup overlay view.